# Migration não é executado em EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, migrations, entity-framework-core

Ao Realizar o Add-Migration Init nenhuma mensagem é mostrada e o migration não é realizado e o prompt fica no estado novamente PM>

Verifiquei que está pegando o EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.3 ao invés do 2.1.3 que é a DLL do nuget que está como referência

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile C:\Users\nicoucc\source\AberturaDeContas\apl-back-core-acd\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\nicoucc.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig C:\Users\nicoucc\source\AberturaDeContas\apl-back-core-acd\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\nicoucc.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.0.3\tools\netcoreapp2.0\ef.dll migrations add Teste --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly C:\Users\nicoucc\source\AberturaDeContas\apl-back-core-acd\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories.dll --startup-assembly C:\Users\nicoucc\source\AberturaDeContas\apl-back-core-acd\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories.dll --project-dir C:\Users\nicoucc\source\AberturaDeContas\apl-back-core-acd\Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories\ --root-namespace Safra.AberturaDeContas.Repositories
>
> Classe Context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {            
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Teste> Testes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

> Classe Facotry Context

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Data Source=3Y1S0L2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AberturaDeContas;User ID=sa;Password=abc102030!;"
        );

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

> Classe Entity

```
public class Teste
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: execute Add-Migration -verbose para  ver o que está sendo executado

Comment: Veja se consegue dar uma olhada na edição que fiz amigo

Comment: @NicolaBogar tente executa direto no terminal, `dotnet ef migrations add %nome%`, outro ponto, está utilizando o EF Core 2.1 ou o 2.0? no 2.1 o tooling já vem no SDK, então dente desinstalar o DotNetCliToolReference.

Comment: Estou usando o 2.1, Essa DLL que você está falando nem está como referencia na minha DLL de repositorio. Aparentemente pelo CMD está indo normal

Comment: Pelo que eu estou vendo, o Migration não está conseguindo escrever o erro que da em algum arquivo para mostrar pra mim no VS2017, porque qual motivo será ? No prompt aparece o erro corretamente

Comment: @TobiasMesquita como executo o Update-Database pelo prompt igual rodei o Migration ?